# using isdigit to inform any detected illegal characters

Tags: c++

I have trouble using isdigit

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
int ndCount[10];

for (x = 0; x < 10; x++,y++) {
cout << y << ". Enter a whole number: ";
    cin >> ndCount[x];
    if (!isdigit(ndCount[x])) {
        cout << "Error, Please try again \n";
     }
    }
   return 0;
 }
```

Whenever I try entering a digit, it would still register as "Error Please try again".
Also, when I try using characters, it would automatically go error

Comment: `isdigit` is meant to check a character.  You are checking `int`'s.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether the user entered a valid number do:

```
if(!(cin >> ndCount[x]))
    throw std::runtime_error("not a number");
```

`operator>>` sets `failbit` of the stream when the value cannot be parsed. Then `operator!` checks whether `failbit` was set.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the value in an `int` you need to store it in a `char`, try `char ndCount[10];`

This will check each digit on the string you enter on the console.

Of course if you want to check an integer you need a different approach.